# Extracting text between 2 specific strings with multiple occurrences in bash

Tags: bash

I have a big xhtml file with lots of junk text that I don't need. I only need whatever text that lies between two specific strings that occur many times within that file, e.g.

```
<html>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<mytag> important text1 </mytag>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<mytag> important text2 </mytag>
<mytag> important text3 </mytag>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
</html>
```

My output should be:

```
important text1
important text2
important text3
```

I need to do that using Bash script.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please note that <xyz> and </xyz> are not fixed strings. There are a lot of different unneeded tags.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex on Xml format is risky, *particularly with line based text processing tool grep*. You cannot make sure that the result is always correct.

If your input was valid xml format, I would go with xml way: xpath expression.

With tool `xmlstarlet`, you can do:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//mytag/text()" file.xml
```

It gives the desired output.

You can also do it with `xmllint`, however, you need do some further filtering on the output.

Comment: Thanks Kent, but the problem is that it's an XHTML file, so it's not well formatted at all, will xmllint be able to handle that?

Comment: @SoCRaT `Extensible Hypertext Markup Language (XHTML) is part of the family of XML markup languages`

Answer (score 0):

Using an XML parser would be the best way to go.

Solution using `grep` with PCRE:

```
grep -Po '^<mytag>\s*\K.*?(?=\s*</mytag>$)'
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.xml                                    
<html>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<mytag> important text1 </mytag>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<mytag> important text2 </mytag>
<mytag> important text3 </mytag>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
</html>

$ grep -Po '^<mytag>\s*\K.*?(?=\s*</mytag>$)' file.xml
important text1
important text2
important text3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using XML parser is a better approach, there are also command line tools for xml parsing in Linux, eg: `xmllint` but you can do it using `grep` like this:

```
$ cat data1 
<html>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<mytag> important text1 </mytag>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
<mytag> important text2 </mytag>
<mytag> important text3 </mytag>
<xyz> unneeded text </xyz>
</html>
$ grep -oP '(?<=<mytag>).*(?=</mytag>)' data1
 important text1 
 important text2 
 important text3  
$
```

`(?<=<mytag>).*(?=</mytag>)` this extracts text using positive lookahead and lookbehind assertions

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test and get back to you